# Docker container takes long to start via shell scripting

Tags: shell, docker, cassandra, scripting

I am new to shell scripting, Recently started with basic. I have written code to check if i have cassandra nodes and it gives me yes or no if no then do execute some command. My problem is i already have started node1 and i am checking if node is already there then get the id of that container and start that container. But when i run it, it gets the id of the container and takes so long and never starts. If i start the container without shell commands it starts. But i want to indulge them in shell.

This is my code:

```
if sudo docker ps -a | grep -q 'node1';then
    sudo docker inspect --format="{{.Id}}" node1
read num    
sudo docker start num
elif sudo docker ps -a | grep -q 'node2';then
    sudo docker inspect --formar="{{.Id}}" node2
read Idnode2 
    sudo docker start Idnode2
else
    sudo docker run --name node1 -d -e CASSANDRA_BROADCAST_ADDRESS=192.168.1.xx -p 7000:7000 cassandra:2
fi
```

output:

```
./tet.sh
f1713abbee52ca465962ec53e97dde62058d37859005f77786db3e3eebe0086c
blinks forever after this
```

I am not getting why its blinking and not executing.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it myself by using this command below

```
if sudo docker ps -a | grep -q 'node1';then
    sudo docker inspect --format="{{.Id}}" node1    
    sudo docker start node1
elif sudo docker ps -a | grep -q 'node2';then
    sudo docker inspect --formar="{{.Id}}" node2
read Idnode2 
    sudo docker start Idnode2
else
    sudo docker run --name node1 -d -e CASSANDRA_BROADCAST_ADDRESS=192.168.1.xx -p 7000:7000 cassandra:2
fi
```